# Can't connect to ASP.Net 4.5 web application using Azure Active Directory to IIS 8.5 on a VM running on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, azure-active-directory

Can not connect to localhost after deploying an ASP.Net 4.5 web application using Azure Active Directory to IIS 8.5 on a VM running on Windows Server 2012 r2

When I attempt to connect to 'http://localhost/', it sends me to authenticate via microsoftonline, but afterwards it redirects back to 'https://localhost:44326' and firefox tells me it can't establish a connection (no error pages).

The webapp was published as a folder on a separate machine. Am I missing server features/roles? Am I missing feature delegations? Any guidance would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you provided the proper app registration url?

Comment: I assume that you want the web application  to direct the user’s browser to sign them in to Azure AD. Can you provider us more information about your configuration? Also, this sample configuration may be helpful:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect

Comment: @Kalyan, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. The application is running on a local machine running a VM. It is meant to be accessed internally.

@ WayneYang-MSFT The configuration I used was the default provided by Visual Studio 2017 community edition. I did not change anything. I'm not sure where to check for more details.

Comment: did you add a Reply URL for your application as hosted on IIS in the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)?. In this portal, on the top bar, click on the signed-in account. Under Directory, select the Azure AD tenant where the app will be registered.
In the navigation on the left, select More Services >. Scroll down and select Azure Active Directory. Select App registrations and find your application. select Settings, and then select Reply URIs, and add the URL of your deployed application